# z3: Order of formulas in conjunction determines unknown vs unsat result

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I am using z3/z3py to solve path constraints in a symbolic interpreter written in Python. z3 currently fails to prove a loop invariant. I tried to isolate the problem, and it seems that the *order* of one particular subformula in a conjunction determines whether z3 yields "unsat" (which is the desired result) or "unknown".

[See edit #2 for a "solution" checking every permutation of a conjunction]

Here's the code:

```py
import z3

fromv, to = z3.Ints(["from", "to"])
t = z3_sequence("t")
subseq = z3_fresh_sequence("subseq")
i = z3.FreshInt("i")

formula = z3.And(
    # z3.Length(t) > i,  # Uncomment -> Solver yields "unknown"

    to <= z3.Length(t),
    z3.IntVal(0) <= fromv,
    fromv <= to,

    i >= fromv,
    i <= to,
    to > i,

    # z3.Length(t) > i,  # Uncomment -> Solver yields "unsat"

    subseq == z3.SubSeq(t, fromv, i - fromv),
    z3.Not(
        z3.And(
            i >= z3.IntVal(-1) + fromv,
            i <= z3.IntVal(-1) + to,
            z3.SubSeq(t, fromv, z3.IntVal(1) + i - fromv) ==
            z3.Concat(subseq, z3.Unit(t[i]))
        )),
)

solver = z3.Solver()
solver.set("timeout", 2000)
solver.add(formula)
print(solver.check())
```

The code depends on the following auxiliary functions for creating constant symbols for sequences of ints:

```py
def z3_fresh_sequence(prefix: str, elem_sort: Optional[z3.SortRef] = None, ctx=None):
    """Returns a fresh sequence constant named `name`. If `ctx=None`, then the global context is used.
    >>> x = z3_fresh_sequence('x')
    """
    ctx = z3.get_ctx(ctx)
    elem_sort = z3.IntSort(ctx) if elem_sort is None else elem_sort
    return z3.SeqRef(
        z3.Z3_mk_fresh_const(
            ctx.ref(),
            prefix,
            z3.SeqSortRef(z3.Z3_mk_seq_sort(elem_sort.ctx_ref(), elem_sort.ast)).ast),
        ctx)


def z3_sequence(name: str, elem_sort: Optional[z3.SortRef] = None, ctx=None):
    """Returns a sequence constant named `name`. If `ctx=None`, then the global context is used.
    >>> x = z3_sequence('x')
    """
    ctx = z3.get_ctx(ctx)
    elem_sort = z3.IntSort(ctx) if elem_sort is None else elem_sort
    return z3.SeqRef(
        z3.Z3_mk_const(ctx.ref(),
                       z3.to_symbol(name, ctx),
                       z3.SeqSortRef(z3.Z3_mk_seq_sort(elem_sort.ctx_ref(), elem_sort.ast)).ast),
        ctx)
```

Uncomment the indicated lines in the first code snippet to obtain the respective results by the solver.

My question now is: *How do I best deal with such problems?* Should I try to randomly throw out or reorder formulas in conjunctions, or is there a better, more systematic way? As usual, increasing / removing the timeout is no solution, as z3 then just takes longer for the "unknown" or does not terminate at all.

Any hints very welcome!

Thanks a lot,
Dominic

## Edit 1: Random shuffling example

I implemented the shuffling idea, which is an interesting experiment. Run the code below, which prints some number of times (usually less than 10) "unknown" and then one formula order which "works":

```py
fromv, to = z3.Ints(["from", "to"])
t = z3_sequence("t")
subseq = z3_fresh_sequence("subseq")
i = z3.FreshInt("i")

formulas = [
    i <= to,
    z3.Not(to <= i),
    0 <= fromv,
    fromv <= to,
    to <= z3.Length(t),
    i >= fromv,

    subseq == z3.SubSeq(t, fromv, i + -1 * fromv),
    z3.Not(z3.And(
        i >= -1 + fromv,
        i <= -1 + to,
        z3.SubSeq(t, fromv, 1 + i + -1 * fromv) ==
        z3.Concat(subseq, z3.Unit(t[i])))),
]

for _ in range(100):
    solver = z3.Solver()
    solver.set("timeout", 500)
    for formula in formulas:
        solver.add(formula)
    result = solver.check()
    print(result)
    if result != z3.unknown:
        print(formulas)
        break
    random.shuffle(formulas)
```

## Edit 2: is_unsat function checking all permutations

I implemented a function `is_unsat` which systematically checks all permutations of a conjunction. This actually works (my loop invariant is successfully proved), but it's not very satisfying. I'll leave that question open for now in case somebody has a better solution.

```py
import itertools
import z3

def is_unsat(formula: z3.BoolRef, timeout_ms=500) -> bool:
    for formulas in itertools.permutations(split_conjunction(formula)):
        solver = z3.Solver()
        solver.set("timeout", timeout_ms)
        for conjunct in formulas:
            solver.add(conjunct)
        result = solver.check()

        if result != z3.unknown:
            break

    return result == z3.unsat


def split_conjunction(formula: z3.BoolRef) -> List[z3.BoolRef]:
    if z3.is_and(formula):
        return [elem for l in [split_conjunction(child) for child in formula.children()] for elem in l]
    else:
        return [formula]
```

Comment: Instead of adding a single formula that has the entire set of conjunctions, add the constraints separately, i.e., using different calls to `s.add`. Not sure if this'll fix it, but it might.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. It's actually exactly what I'm doing in my edits one and two, adding conjuncts one at a time; but only certain orderings do work!

Comment: If you distill this to a minimal example, reporting it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues might be a good idea to get the developers to take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, might be the way to go. Just submitted a report: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5559 Reducing the example while keeping that behavior proved to be quite difficult, though, so kept the example due to time constraints

Comment: If you snoop around Z3's issue tracker for a bit, you'll find several similar reports. If I'm not mistaken, the answer was always that Z3 is heuristics-driven (for many subtheories) and that the program code (names of variables, order of conjuncts, order of commands, etc.) can affect these heuristics — alas. But good luck nonetheless.

Comment: I got a reply by Nikolaj Bjorner (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5559#issuecomment-923132467): Obviously, the issue is the mixture of sequence and integer constraints. Nikolaj suggests to experiment with different random seeds, shorter timeouts, or parallel runs, since the issue's been open for a while. Not really satisfactory...